# Please help with indetifying logical consequence.

Tags: propositional-calculus

Let's say that it is true that: a conclusion A is a logical consequence of a set of premises T iff negation of A is in T and T is not finitely performable. Formally written: (T ⊨ A) ⇔ T ⋃ {¬A} is not satisfiable.

My question is the following: What Is the logical consequence of saying that It is NOT TRUE that the conclusion A is a logical consequence of a set of premises T? Is the logical consequence that T ⋃ {¬A}  is always satisfiable?

Comment: What do you mean with "finitely performable" ?

Comment: The natural language wording is wrong : "$T \cup \{ ¬A \}$ is not finitely performable" reads "the set formed by T and the negation of A is not finitely performable".

Comment: Sorry, by the word "performable" I mean "satisfiable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start from the end and answer your question - no, that's not the logical consequence. I will now explain why.

Your theorem concerning the relation between entailmaent is correct. Let's write it again.

$ T \models A \Leftrightarrow T\cup \{ \neg A\} $ is not satisfiable

This is logically equivalent to:

$ \neg ( T \models A ) \Leftrightarrow \neg ( T\cup \{ \neg A\} $ is not satisfiable )

Meaning:

$ \neg ( T \models A ) \Leftrightarrow ( T\cup \{ \neg A\} $ is satisfiable )

Now the thing is to bear in mind what satisfinability is: A set of formulas is satisfable $ \Leftrightarrow $ there exists a model in which all the formulas receive as truth-value of true in that model. In our case - there exists a model where T receives a True truth-value while   **$ \neg A $** received a truth value of True also. Which means that $A$ receives a truth-value of False. Which is clearly our definition when the premises do not entail the consequence in an argument.

Hope this helps.